# Interval Based Batch Processor For Fire And Forget Commands On Redis

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, design-patterns, redis

I'm building a trade engine for cryptocurrency and since the trade engine is going to get consumed by a lot of commands in multiple markets, I was wondering instead of using a default pattern like issuing a threat for each command there can be a DataBase that saves commands for short periods of time and executes them in a batch.
I was wondering if it's a good idea and is there a pattern or delivery mechanism I can use for my database?

Comment: question: what are you trying to achieve by batching here? what is the thing you're hoping that will be different to just sending them immediately? and what do you mean by "issuing a thread for each command" (although I think we've all wanted to add a "do this properly or I unplug you for good" addendum when talking to the server) ? I need to understand these to understand the scenario (note: I'm the author of at least 2 redis libraries in .NET, and have contributed significant amounts of code to a 3rd, so I'm *probably* going to have a reasonable idea of options here)

Comment: well, the thought that I had was if I implement this design my system CPU will almost never be fully consumed by requests, and RAM will have to do the heavy lifting as result the system always is responsive sure maybe with some added delay, I use rabbit MQ for talking to the server, also I understand that RMQ uses an event bus and system always will be responsive but I thought with this scenario there will be less cost on CPU and more on RAM.
issuing a thread for each command: I meant a Dotnet Async Task

Comment: OK; now: what redis library are you using? If you're using StackExchange.Redis: add `CommandFlags.FireAndForget` to your command, and you're done - no thread will be tied up, they'll just be pipelined down the socket (just: make sure you reuse the same multiplexer instance between requests; don't spin up a multiplexer per message); and if you don't really mean fire and forget: just use the async API surface: no thread blocking

Comment: Greate just one question is it not more beneficial to execute FireAndForget Comments in a batch? considering using the same multiplexer.

Comment: not really, no; you *might* get slightly reduced packet fragmentation using batching, but usually this isn't a problem, and the "pipelines" infrastructure means that most of the time you'd get dense packets *anyway* if there's sufficient data, even without batching; source: I wrote the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question here seems to be focused around CPU blocking when issuing redis commands, with a mention of fire and forget.

In the general case, then yes: with any client, a blocking synchronous call such as:

```cs
redis.call("incr", "foo");
```

is going to block the current thread for an instance of latency, however: different clients have different capabilities; let's assume that we're using StackExchange.Redis as the library, and compare to:

```cs
db.StringIncrement("foo"); // blocks current thread
```

We have a few options here, though:

```cs
// doesn't block thread, completes asynchronously, reactivated via task model with result
await.StringIncrememtAsync("foo");

// doesn't block thread; result is meaningless (default(T))
db.StringIncrement("foo", flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);

// doesn't block thread, completes synchronously via a completed task with
// meaningless result (default(T))
await db.StringIncrementAsync("foo", flags: CommandFlags.FireAndForget);
```

So there are multiple ways to avoid CPU blocking.

As for batching: in some cases batching can help reduce packet fragmentation, but since we're using "pipelines" as a buffer between the layers, we'll already be doing a fair job of creating dense packets if there is sufficient data, and if there *isn't* sufficient data to fill packets: there's not really any harm sending them earlier, and avoiding latency/buffering; unless you're sending multiple *related* commands in close proximity, the batching API is not usually immediately useful (and when you *are* sending multiple related commands - it may also be useful to compare/contrast the batching vs transaction APIs).